# Can I save passwords securely and retrieve them without asking for a master password?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to understand how to save passwords used on my app securely, so the user doesn't have to remember them but at the same time nobody can get them looking at the data from my app.

I imagine the files containing the passwords should be encrypted, my doub is whether the user would have to input a "master password" to retrieve stored passwords or if there is any way so that only my app can retrieve them without any input from the user.

Can my app retrieve the passwords without the user needing to write a master password? How is this done?

Comment: This question is platform-specific. Ian's answer is great for Windows. If you need something else, you need to indicate your platform. Without some kind of OS support, this isn't possible.

Comment: hi Rob, we plan to launch on Android, iOS, Windows and OSX. I didn't know it was platform specific. I thought there was a method for the app to do this.

Comment: Basically you cannot secure something without a secret. Best is of course to only ask for the password when establishing a session. If you have to store, the answer of Ian already shows the way: you need system support. So look up the various options made available to you on the platform of choice. These won't be the same, so you may need to define a generic interface and then implement it for each platform (if you want to keep to the same application design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows your best solution is to use the **Data Protection API**, used by Chrome, IE, Remote Desktop Connection, and dozens of other technologies, to encrypt data.

The virtue is that the data is encrypted (in a round-about way) with the user's own Windows password. When the user types their password into Windows, it makes all the *"protected"* data available.

Features:

- the data is encrypted
- the user doesn't have to enter their password to encrypt data
- only the user can ever decrypt it
- the user does not have to enter their password to decrypt data

## Sample pseudo-code

The API you want is `CryptProtectData` and `CryptUnprotectData`:

```
public bytes[] ProtectBytes(bytes[] plaintext)
{
   DATA_BLOB dataIn;
   dataIn.cbData = plaintext.Length;
   dataIn.pbData = Addr(plaintext[0]);

   DATA_BLOB dataOut;

   BOOL bRes = CryptProtectData(
         dataIn,
         null,     //data description (optional PWideChar)
         null,     //optional entropy (PDATA_BLOB)
         null,     //reserved
         null,     //prompt struct
         CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN,
         ref dataOut);
   if (!bRes) then
   {
      DWORD le = GetLastError();
      throw new Win32Error(le, "Error calling CryptProtectData");
   }

   //Copy ciphertext from dataOut blob into an actual array
   bytes[] result;
   SetLength(result, dataOut.cbData);
   CopyMemory(dataOut.pbData, Addr(result[0]), dataOut.cbData);

   //When you have finished using the DATA_BLOB structure, free its pbData member by calling the LocalFree function
   LocalFree(HANDLE(dataOut.pbData)); //LocalFree takes a handle, not a pointer. But that's what the SDK says.
}
```

Later, when you need to decrypt the blob, you use `CryptProtectData`.

The data is (effectively) encrypted with the user's Windows password; and only the person with their Windows password can decrypt it.

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.